# Why is the anti-aliasing so bad in this text with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, logo, anti-aliasing

I am trying to use Gimp to create a logo. I have the fonts that I need already. No matter what font I use in GIMP I see really obvious anti-aliasing on the text. I suspect this is caused by GIMP and not the font because if I use the very same font in Word or a web page opened with Chrome it renders just fine.

What can I do in gimp to increase the quality of this? I tried increasing the DPI of the image but that didn't work.

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT: The shrinking of the image to fit in this question seems to have blurred and slightly improved the lines on the text. Click through to see the original with the really bad anti-aliasing.

Comment: Did you alter anything in that screenshot after making it? It looks scaled up (and yes, I know that I have to click on the image to view the original).

Comment: No altering. I just took a screenshot using CMD+SHIFT+4 on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: Ah, I guess it's the high ppi image displayed on a low ppi screen then. Might make it hard to impossible to provide advice, though.